# In SwiftUI, a NavigationBarItem, in a View pushed by a NavigationLink embedded inside a ScrollView inside a List or Form, doesn't work?

Tags: scrollview, swiftui, navigationview

When using a `NavigationLink` inside a `ScrollView` inside a `List` or `Form` to push `TestDetail()`, the `NavigationLink` works, but the `navigationBarItems` in `TestDetail()` do not work.

Here is a code snippet which replicates the issue. Notice that item 1 works, but item 2 fails. Can anyone please advise me on what I might be doing wrong?

```
struct TestMaster: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                /// 1. Success - NavigationLink pushes TestDetail and trailing NavigationBarItem works
                NavigationLink(destination: TestDetail()) {
                    Text("Success")
                }

                /// 2. Failure - NavigationLink inside ScrollView pushes TestDetail, but NavigationBarItem doesn't work
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: TestDetail()) {
                            Text("Failure")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestDetail: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Nothing, just testing ...")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    print("printing something ...")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Print")
                })
        )
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated as per @Asperi's comment below.

Comment: It is not ScrollView it is List, because if you replace List with anything else, navigation bar items are added and work as expected.

Comment: @Asperi, if I replace List with Form, I get the same behavior. If I replace List with VStack, I get the expected behavior, but lose the layout of a List or Form. Your suggestion does not solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: It was not suggestion, just narrow area of bug. And by the way, Form uses List inside.

Comment: @Asperi, cool, thank you!